# What is the proof of $(c\geq a-b)\land(c\geq b-a)\implies c\geq |a-b|$, and what is it called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I encountered this in one question to proof something.

$$ (c \geq a-b) \land (c \geq b-a) \;\implies\; c \geq  |a-b|  $$

What is the proof for this, and what is it called?

Comment: Proof: $|a-b|$ is $a-b$ or $b-a$ and the conclusion holds in both cases.

Comment: Equivalently, $\max(q,-q)= |q|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d:=a-b$.

$$c\ge d\land c\ge-d\implies c\ge\max(d,-d)=|d|.$$

---

We could have added this lemma:

$$d\ge0\implies\max(d,-d)=d=|d|$$ and

$$d\le0\implies\max(d,-d)=-d=|d|.$$